# jquery ajax post to .aspx page load - how to read variable posted?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, vb.net, json

I am trying to do a ajax  post to a aspx page . How do I read the variable "myVar"?
 in the code below  `HttpContext.Current.Request("myVar")` brings back nothing

```
var p = { "myVar": JSON.stringify(tableOBJ) };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default2AJAX.aspx",
    data: p,
    success: function (data) {

    }
});
```

**Default2AJAX.aspx code behind**

```
Partial Class Default2AJAX
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim s As String = HttpContext.Current.Request("myVar") ''not working???????

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("myVar")
```